# jQuery toggling between two objects on one item click

Tags: jquery

This should be a simple one but since im a bit tied on time i figured id ask... Anyways I was just wondering how could I make two things toggle for eg. I want a div to show then hide (slide effect) and at the same time the link that does this effect to change text... I have this code currently...

```
/* Show/Hide */
$("#statusDisplayH").live("click", function(){
    $("#statusH").slideToggle("medium");


    if($("#statusH").is(":visible"))
    {
        $("#statusDisplayH").text("HIDE");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#statusDisplayH").text("SHOW");
    }
});
```

where statusH is the div to show/hide and statusDisplayH is a link "a href..." and of course the link is not inside the div... Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is the question?  Is the current code not working for you?

Comment: @N Rohler the slidetoggle works but changing the text only displays Hide then doesnt toggle anymore....

Comment: I'll post some cleaned-up code below... just a second...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the callback on `.slideToggle()`:

```
/* Show/Hide */
$("#statusDisplayH").live("click", function(){
    var toToggle = $("#statusH");
    toToggle.slideToggle("medium", function(){
        $("#statusDisplayH").text( toToggle.is(":visible") ? "HIDE IT" : "SHOW IT"); 
    });
});
```